# Prove that in a sequence of chained subsets, the intersection is finite and nonempty

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory

The heading is merely a simplified version. Currently, I am reading Understanding Analysis and working on the preliminaries. The question is:

If $A_1 \supseteq A_2 \supseteq A_3 \supseteq A_4\cdots$ are all finite, nonempty sets of real numbers, then the intersection $\bigcap_{n=1}^\infty A_n$ is finite and nonempty.

The book at this point has not formally defined finite. In addition, the only hint, in my opinion, offered by the book is the following question,

If $A_1 \supseteq A_2 \supseteq A_3 \supseteq A_4\cdots$ are all sets containing an infinite number of elements, then the intersection $\bigcap_{n=1}^\infty A_n$ is infinite as well.

With this question and an aforementioned example, I can solve this problem by defining the set $A_i = \{i,i+1,i+2\dots\}\subseteq N$ and a proof by contradiction.

However, when it comes to $A_i$ containing finite elements, I just don't now how to

1. Prove by definition
2. Understand the intuition behind can't find a counter example like the infinite version

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1745569/proof-intersection-is-finite-and-non-empty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to notice that a decreasing sequence of positive integers, in this case the cardinalities of the sets $A_k$, must eventually be constant. For $k\in\Bbb Z^+$ let $n_k=|A_k|$, the number of elements in $A_k$; $n_k$ is a positive integer. Let $N=\{n_k:k\in\Bbb Z^+\}$; $N$ is a non-empty set of positive integers, so it has a smallest element $m$. Let $\ell\in\Bbb Z^+$ be such that $n_\ell=m$.

$A_{\ell+1}\subseteq A_\ell$, so $n_{\ell+1}\le n_\ell=m$. But $m=\min N$, so $n_{\ell+1}\ge m$, and therefore $n_{\ell+1}=m$. Thus, $A_{\ell+1}\subseteq A_\ell$ and $|A_{\ell+1}|=|A_\ell|$ , so $A_{\ell+1}=A_\ell$. You can use this idea to prove by induction that $A_k=A_\ell$ for every $k\ge\ell$. Then you’re almost done. $A_k\supseteq A_\ell$ for $k=1,\ldots,\ell$, and $A_k=A_\ell$ for $k>\ell$, so

$$\bigcap_{k\ge 1}A_k=\bigcap_{k=1}^\ell A_k\cap\bigcap_{k>\ell}A_k=A_\ell\cap A_\ell=A_\ell\,.$$

Comment: Thanks for the answer. However, after doing some more research, it seems that induction sometimes fails in infinity case. Precisely speaking, $P(n)$'s true doesn't necessarily mean $P(\infty)$'s true. In particular, I understand how things work for a given large enough integer and one integer after it. But, can I extend this to infinity? The real confusion here is on one hand natural number is infinite per se; on the hand induction sometimes can't help infinite case. So, does your proof use induction? If yes, why so? If not, how to differentiate it?

Comment: @AndesLam: There is no $P(\infty)$ here: there is simply a $P(k)$ for each integer $k\ge\ell$, and we prove that $P(k)$ is true for each of those integers. This shows that all of the $A_k$ with $k\ge\ell$ are the same finite size, and since they are nested, they must all be the same set. That makes it clear that their intersection is also that set. The case of infinite sets $A_k$ is completely different and doesn’t involve induction at all.

Comment: Yes, I understand the proof. In fact, the proof is so beautifully written. What I am doing here is not altering the proof. Instead, I am trying to connect with induction. You mentioned about $\forall k\geq\ell$ such that $P(k)$ is true. I understand. But it is also my understand that induction doesn't help $P(\infty)$ and the question is asking for infinite intersection notation-wise. So, does proving $\forall k\geq\ell$ does the same work and not induction at the same time?

Comment: @AndesLam: Once again, there is no $P(\infty)$. The argument that $\bigcap_kA_k=A_\ell$ uses the **result** of the induction argument, i.e., the fact that $A_k=A_\ell$ for all $k\ge \ell$, but it is not in any way part of that argument. It’s an independent calculation — specifically, the calculation in the displayed formula.